# Radio button focus in typescript/angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

How can I make radio button get focused on the tabbing and get selected when clicking on enter in angular 2?

```
<div class="radio-group-container">
    <md-radio-group class="radio-group" [(ngModel)]="choice" tabIndex="11" (click)="radioClick()" disableRipple>
        <md-radio-button class="radio-button" *ngFor="let choice of choices" [value]="choice" tabIndex="13" disableRipple>{{choice}}</md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the radio buttons that are created using  have the same tabIndex in your code. Try replacing it with

```
<md-radio-button class="radio-button" *ngFor="let choice of choices; let i=index" [value]="choice" tabIndex="index" disableRipple>{{choice}}</md-radio-button>
```

Comment: If tabindex should start from 11 then how can initialise index?

Comment: I wasn't able to make work tabindex on radio buttons, but following the logic, I think tabIndex="11+index" should work